# Task Manager shows thousands of processes named "ls", how do I find out what is causing this and stop it?

Tags: windows, task-manager

Recently when trying to find out why my computer was slowing down, I saw on Task Manager (which is taking several seconds to open, if it opens correctly at all) that there were thousands of entries under the Processes tab named "ls":

[image]

How can I track down what is causing this many "ls" processes to open? As a temporary fix, my computer goes back to normal after a reset.

Currently I have no reason to believe it is any kind of malware. Windows' Virus and Thread protection didn't find anything after running a full scan.

Comment: With [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) you might be able to see what process has started the `ls` processes.

Comment: Try right clicking the process and click "Go to details".  That will tell you what program is creating the processes.

Comment: @Salocor Right clicking on it showed a white square, I think the UI wasn't able to display the information. I'll try again next time I see the issue.

Comment: @Bodo Ah, I should have tried that. I assume this will happen again so I'll make sure I report back what I find.

Comment: @Moab Not quite. I am not sure if it even is malware to begin with.